# How can I connect to a Microsoft Dynamics CRM server using Python?

Tags: python, web-services, dynamics-crm, ntlm, dynamics-crm-2011

The Microsoft Dynamics CRM service uses NTLM authentication, which makes connecting to it from a python process using suds somewhat complicated. I'm looking for a code sample that will:

1. Send and receive the response from a `RetrieveAttributeRequest`
2. Send and receive the response from an `Execute` request.

This must use Python 2.6 or Python 2.7, not Python 3. I already have a working implementation that uses curl to do this, but it's flaky at the best of times, and as part of some other work I have in this tool I'd like to clean it up and make it run using python/suds.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit late but hopefully it will help someone.

NTLM authentication was added to suds in [version 0.3.8](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/84).

```
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated
from suds.client import Client

url = 'http://crmurl/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl'
ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='DOMAIN\username', password='password')
client = Client(url, transport=ntlm)
```

Comment: 5 years later, `suds` has been abandoned. However `pip install suds-community` seems to at least install, & here's the github page for that: https://github.com/suds-community/suds

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of help to you, but I used [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) to get through an NTLM proxy.

Here's a code snippet:

```
    c = Curl()

    c.setopt(URL, 'http://www.somesite.com')
    c.setopt(FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)           # follow redirects
    c.setopt(MAXREDIRS, 5)              # max redirects
    c.setopt(PROXY, 'proxy.somesite.com')
    c.setopt(PROXYUSERPWD, 'DOMAIN/USER:PASSWORD')
    c.setopt(PROXYAUTH, HTTPAUTH_NTLM)    # use NTLM

    c.perform()
```

Here's the [documentation](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html) on the `Curl` object.

Comment: Right now we use curl to do the work here, but that means that we have to handle serializing and deserializing the XML on each call, and building SOAP messages by hand is not fun. I'd rather a solution that abstracts that out, without having to write it by hand myself.