# Connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK from Python

Tags: python, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Has anyone had any luck connecting to the 2011 endpoints in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 using Python?  I've installed SUDS and can grab the WSDL, but service calls return 400 Bad Request.  I'm sure it's because I'm not authenticated, but I'm not quite sure how to authenticate using raw SOAP.  I know about [Girish's code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CRM-Online-2011-WebServices-14913a16) but am not familiar enough with SOAP to go much further.

I see this was asked [a year ago on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294587/how-can-i-connect-to-a-microsoft-dynamics-crm-server-using-python) but that question seems to be about NTLM.  In my case, I want to use WS-Trust.

Here is the code I've got:

```
from suds.client import Client
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

url = 'https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl'
client = Client(url)

req = client.factory.create('ns3:RetrieveOrganizationsRequest')
accessTypes = client.factory.create('ns3:AccessType')
orgRel = client.factory.create('ns3:OrganizationRelease')
req.AccessType = accessTypes.Default
req.Release = orgRel.Current

headers = dict()
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/soap+xml'
client.set_options(headers=headers)

resp = client.service.Execute(req)
```

Comment: ever have any success with this?

Comment: Nope, never got it working and lost interest in the project, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If using SOAP isn't a requirement -- consider the [RESTish Odata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx) service.  I'm no Python expert -- but you could run through GET requests in a browser and use the debugger tools to see what the browser sends for headers and mimic this in your Python code.  You'd have some choice over what format the service returns (JSON or XML) as well by modifying the Content-Type header.

Comment: Unfortunately the REST Odata service is not available to external services:

"Authentication is only possible within the application.
Use of the REST endpoint is limited to JScript libraries or Silverlight web resources."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx

Comment: You can use the REST interface from outside if you immitate a person in a browser to get the auth stuff in the cookie, then use the cookie to make subsequent requests. I did it using a combination of 'requests' (for HTTP communication) and 'BeautifulSoup' (for scraper style parsing) to jump through the hoops to logging in. The code looks more or less like a mini scraper. Since the our login is provided by a local proprietary cloud provider my code probably won't be a whole lot of use.

It's worth noting though that in some respects, such as result set size, the REST interface is limited.