# CRM Dynamics & Python via FetchXML

Tags: python, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm using Python for data analysis and I would like to connect to my CRM Dynamics server by using FecthXML queries.

I do not know how to set up my connection through Python.

Some docs regarding connection via Visual Studio are available but I would like to build my dashboard only via Python.

Is it possible ?
Does somebody get some example of Python Fetch XML set up ?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the post in the link below for more details on how to connect to Dynamics CRM using Python.

[How can I connect to a Microsoft Dynamics CRM server using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294587/how-can-i-connect-to-a-microsoft-dynamics-crm-server-using-python)